# Is it good to use Apache.Spark to manage of tasks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, scheduled-tasks, task

I develop new python application. It consist of two parts: server and workers. The server must start tasks and manage of whole life cycle of program. Worker is application, which is able to complete one task.

I want to use Apache Spark. Is it right method to manage of tasks? If not, what kind of software I should use for manage of tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you're trying to do, but it does not sound like Apache Spark is the right choice. It's a distributed computation system, not a task manager. Check out it's documentation to get a good idea of what it is: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: I read docs and see screencasts. I know, that Spark is a distributed computation system. But, according this https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/img/cluster-overview.png , my application may use Spark as task manager, may not?

Comment: If you want to manage Spark tasks, then yes.

Comment: so, my question have sense. If my worker is a parser, it is good to consider, that worker is Spark task?

Comment: No. Your worker is not a Spark task.

Comment: I am sorry, but why not? My parser is standalone application. I have cluster of parsers (each parser is deployed to unique server).

Comment: Spark tasks are not generic processes. They are units of computation managed by Spark. Perhaps the best way to understand would be if you tried to use Spark to manage your tasks. You will immediately see that it is not a task manager.